# Google maps API zipcode to zipcode driving directions

Tags: google-maps, gcloud

I am following Google gCloud guidelines to plot a map (to embed inside an iframe). In my problem, origin and destinations are numeric zipcodes.

This is the URL I use:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=MY_API_KEY&origin=address=07304&destination=90210
```

This is what I get:
[image]

When I should get this:
[image]

This pickups the real origin (Jersey City, NJ), but for the 90210 (Beverly Hills, CA) it picks up a business in Queens, NY (90210 Laser).

Is there a way to specify ZIPCODE origin and ZIPCODE destination in the URL without having to first get lat, lon or city names; just like when "07304" is specified?

I am not limited to Google Maps, any free or low cost service that can encode zip code to zip code directions correctly is a good solution.

Thanks

Comment: you could also use place_ids: `origin=place_id:ChIJc9ESSthQwokR2_RHrCg_lwY&destination=place_id:ChIJ7xfS-zW8woARXNkAJzX5Hs`. You can check [Embed API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/map-generator#generating_an_iframe) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option would be: `origin=zip 07304&destination=zip 90210`

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=[API_KEY]&origin=zip 07304&destination=zip 90210" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[live example](http://geocodezip.com/embed_example_zipcode2zipcode2.html)
[image: screenshot of live example]